# Gradient of Semi Log Curve in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, linear-gradients, quadratic

I need help in automating to get the gradient slope on the graph with the input for the x-value for the graph.

The graph is void ratio against Pressure. Values are as follows for the top curved region of the graph.

```
kPa           
13 
25 
50 
100 
160 
250 
410 

Void Ratio
1.109 
1.096 
1.079 
1.035 
0.993 
0.945 
0.894
```

This is what I did. I used the trend line function to get the approximate curve, which was almost accurate to get a simple quadratic equation. I used `"INDEX(LINEST($I$45:$I$51,$C$45:$C$51^{1,2}),1)"` to get the individual values in a cell, which then I got the derivative equation to generate the slope.

The problem is, I can't get the automatic tangent similar to that of drawn manually. I believe the issue here is the semi-log plot. How can this be circumvented?

[void ratio vs kPa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q37E.jpg)

Comment: for the image:

https://ibb.co/deSQ4w